# Faster way to count number of string occurrences in a numpy array python

Tags: python, arrays, string, performance, numpy

I have a numpy array of tuples:

```
trainY = np.array([('php', 'image-processing', 'file-upload', 'upload', 'mime-types'),
                   ('firefox',), ('r', 'matlab', 'machine-learning'),
                   ('c#', 'url', 'encoding'), ('php', 'api', 'file-get-contents'),
                   ('proxy', 'active-directory', 'jmeter'), ('core-plot',),
                   ('c#', 'asp.net', 'windows-phone-7'),
                   ('.net', 'javascript', 'code-generation'),
                   ('sql', 'variables', 'parameters', 'procedure', 'calls')], dtype=object)
```

I am given list of indices which subsets this np.array:

```
x = [0, 4]
```

and a string:

```
label = 'php'
```

I want to count the number of times the label `'php'` occurs in this subset of the np.array. In this case, the answer would be 2.

Notes:

1) A label will only appear at most ONCE in a tuple and

2) The tuple can have length from 1 to 5.

3) Length of the list `x` is typically 7-50.

4) Length of `trainY` is approx 0.8mil

My current code to do this is:

```
sum([1 for n in x if label in trainY[n]])
```

This is currently a performance bottleneck of my program and I'm looking for a way to make it much faster.  I think we can skip the loop over `x` and just do a vectorised looking up `trainY` like `trainY[x]` but I couldn't get something that worked.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you making this calculation a lot of times for the same `trainY`?
You might consider doing some preprocessing on `trainY`

Comment: Yes it's the same `trainY`.  The things that are changing is `label` and the indices `x`

Comment: Shorter version of your current code: `sum(label in words for words in trainY[x])`. (I don't know if that will make much difference in performance.)

Comment: length of `x` is small. The sum should compute instantly. If it is a bottleneck in your program; it means you compute the sum many many times. Please, provide context for the code. You might find an optimization opportunity there. How much faster does your program get if you remove the `sum()`  call and replace it with a dummy constant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think using [Counters](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) may be a good option in this case.

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter([i for j in trainY for i in j])

print c['php'] # Returns 2
print c.most_common(5) # Print the 5 most common items.
```

Comment: good answer, just adding: to print the OP's desired item you can do `c['php']`

Comment: it would also be faster to do `c=Counter([i for j in trainY for i in j])` instead of the for loop...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.in1d` after flattening your array with a list comprehension:

```
trainY = np.array([i for j in trainY for i in j])
ans = np.in1d(trainY, 'php').sum()
# 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider building a dictionary of the form:

```
{'string1': (1,2,5),
 'string2': (3,4,5),
 ...
}
```

for every word, hold a sorted list of the indices it appeared in the tuples.
hope it makes sense...